# Comparing statical significance on a line chart

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

I have a line chart similar to the one below that shows the change in mean values over time for 5 datasets (A, B, C, and D).

[image]

As you can see the plot includes error bars representing 1 +/- standard error.

What is the best / preferred way to indicate significance between the 5 data set for a given day **and** the significance of the change day to day for each data set?

How might one accomplish this in R?  I'm familiar with the [ggsignif](https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif) package but can't figure out if there's a way to apply it to my situation.

Comment: i think anova would be suitable

Comment: any details on how to do this in R and what the formula might be?

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/analysis-of-variance-anova-for-multiple-comparisons/